# Pass array into google.maps.LatLng via apply()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Trying to understand `apply()` a little better. I think this a great use case, it just doesn't work.

I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: function apply() { [native code] } is not a constructor`

When I try to apply to `google.maps.LatLng`

`new google.maps.LatLng.apply(null, hospital)`

or

`new google.maps.LatLng().apply(null, hospital)`

### Update

**This works**

```
new google.maps.LatLng.apply(40.670287895547006,-73.9865255355835)
```

**This fails**

```
new google.maps.LatLng.apply(null, [40.670287895547006,-73.9865255355835])
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `apply`

Comment: @SepOSep pass an array of two values rather then two separate arguments.

Comment: Are you saying you have an array, like `[123, 345]`, and you want to "apply" it to the `google.maps.LatLng` constructor? So that it **technically calls** `new google.maps.LatLng(123, 345)`?

Comment: @SepOSep yes exactly!

Comment: @Ian Ok didn't realize it was about `new`